# Passing the child instance on construction

Tags: java, generics

I have a parent class which has methods that need to utilize the child's class instance, but I can't seem to pass it via constructor:

```
public abstract class CodelanxPlugin<E extends CodelanxPlugin<E>> /* other inheritance */ {

    private final E plugin;

    public CodelanxPlugin(E plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        //need to be able to use the plugin instance
    }

}
```

However, because the child class has to be able to collect a child instance in some form before `onEnable` is called, I essentially came to this:

```
public class MyPlugin extends CodelanxPlugin<MyPlugin> {

public MyPlugin() {
    super(this);
}
```

Which is of course not possible since you can't `super(this)`. How can I pass up the child instance upon construction?

One idea I had was:

```
public MyPlugin() {
    super(new Box<MyPlugin>(this).getInst());
}

private class Box<E> {

    private E inst;

    public Box(E inst) {
        this.inst = inst;
    }

    public E getInst() {
        return this.inst;
    }
}
```

However it still calls `this` before the super() is called, so it's still illegal.

One reason I cannot simple use `this` in the parent class in the first place is that I pass `E` as the type argument for some other classes:

```
protected ListenerManager<E> listener;

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    //...
    this.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "Enabling listeners...");
    this.listener = new ListenerManager<>(/* need the E instance */);
    //...
}
```

If I pass `this` to the `ListenerManager` constructor, I receive this compiler error:

> error: incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for ListenerManager<>

If I use `new ListenerManager<E>(this)`, then my error is:

> error: incompatible types: CodelanxPlugin cannot be converted to E

Comment: There is no good reason to use `class CodelanxPlugin<E extends CodelanxPlugin<E>>` instead of just `class CodelanxPlugin<E>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply don't need to pass "this" to your parent's constructor.  'this' inside MyPlugin's constructor refer to the same object as 'this' inside CodelanxPlugin's constructor.

So what you are writing is simply:

```
 public CodelanxPlugin() {
    this.plugin = (E) this;
}
```

And then, you should wonder wy you'd need a "plugin" field anyway, since "this" will always be available... From your explanation, I feel that you are looking for the [template method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: Well the main issue is that `this` doesn't equate to the plugin instance itself, since I have subclasses which I am passing `E` to. I'll update my question

Comment: Sorry to insist, but in your update code, why can't you simply write `this.listener = new ListenerManager<>((E) this);` ?

Comment: Hah! Casting! I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: No, generics are indeed a common source of confusion. They might help a lot, but proper use require a throughful understanding, and manual cast tricks are unfortunately a frequent necessity, especially when passing one's class as parameter to one's parent.

Comment: This cast is unsafe. `E` is a subtype of `CodelanxPlugin<E>`, but `CodelanxPlugin<E>` (the type of `this`) is not a subtype of `E`. (If it were safe then a cast would not be needed in the first place.)

Comment: Unsafe, indeed, because it is assumed here that `E` designate the class of `this`. `E` could technically designate the type of some delegate (which would also be a subtype of CodelanxPlugin). How serious is this constraint? I personally consider that well documented constraints (for example in JavaDoc) have almost the same value as constraints implied by generics parameters, given that ignoring generics contracts is so easy.

Comment: Now, it could also be said that in the current situation, avoiding the "E designate the type of `this`" assumption is probably easy. Can't ListenerManager be defined as `ListenerManager<CodelanxPlugin>`? Can't we add a method `protected abstract E getPlugin();`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confused about how subclassing works.  (Either that or I'm completely confused about what you're trying to accomplish.)  If you have a class `C` and a subclass `Sub`:

```
class C {
}

class Sub extends C {
}
```

When the program says `new Sub()`, it creates one new instance.  This object is an instance of `Sub`, and it is also an instance of `C`.  It doesn't make sense to talk about the methods of `C` referring to "the child instance".

If you have a `Sub` object:

```
Sub myObject = new Sub();
```

and you call a method that runs code in `C`:

```
class C {
    public void someMethod() {
        // someMethod logic
    }
}

myObject.someMethod();
```

and let's say that method is not overridden.  So now you're in the section marked `someMethod logic`.  Within that section, `this` refers to the object instance you're calling it for (`myObject`)--which is **both** an instance of `C` and an instance of `Sub`.  You do not need a separate syntax to refer to "the child instance", because there's no such separate thing.

So in your original example, if your intent is for the `plugin` field to be "the child instance of the same object you're just creating", get rid of it.  You don't need it.

On the other hand, if you're creating a new object and giving the new object a reference to a different, *previously created* object, that's a whole other story.  But that's not how I understood your question.

Comment: Yes up until the point of generics, where say, `Sub extends C<Sub>` != `C<E extends C<E>>` in the parent class, which seems to be my problem with the compiler.